# How to disable sidebar font smoothing (antialiasing) in Firefox 89?

Tags: firefox, fonts

- OS: Windows 7
- Firefox: 89.0 (32-bit)
- Description: Fonts in the sidebar (history, bookmarks) are blurred (like when ClearType is on). All other application fonts (Firefox UI, web pages) are OK.

I've tried these settings in userChrome.css without luck:

```
.sidebar-placesTree treechildren::-moz-tree-cell-text {
    font-smooth: never !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: none !important;
}
```

How can I disable this smoothing?

Answer (score 1):

about:config

```
gfx.text.disable-aa = true
```

Comment: Nice find.  That will disable it everywhere in Firefox.  Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: Yes. Sidebar and development tools where the only FF parts remaining "smoothed" in Windows. Found it on some Linux forum while trying to disable AA completely in FF in Linux Mint on a low-res laptop.

Comment: Sounds good.  If, BTW, you need any help disabling AA completely on Windows (all applications plus the OS itself), just let me know and I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Well, seems not so good as I initially thought. It disables smoothing completely. Actually, I want FF to keep the default Windows font smoothing, but disable ClearType-like smoothing.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I think you may have that a little off.  The default Windows font smoothing is the ClearType smoothing.

Comment: Windows, for years (since XP at least, I think it existed in 98 too) has (still) a nice light smoothing method, non-ClearType. This is what I mean and this is the method I use.

For some reason FF doesn't respect this global OS settings for sidebar and dev tools, all other parts of FF are OK.

Comment: Hmmm... Odd that it wouldn't respect it for sidebar and dev tools ***only***.  I'm not experiencing the same thing, but that doesn't surprise me as this sort of thing often needs all the stars to be aligned to reproduce.  Might be worth filing a bugzilla report.  I do experience an issue with red text getting hard to read on one site.  It comes and goes as the page updates its content.  But that issue is in the viewport, so may not be related.

Comment: `gfx.text.disable-aa = true` helps for Thunderbird too (just note that you need to restart Thunderbird to apply the effect). It fixes blurry fonts in sidebar and mail list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing `gfx.text.disable-aa` you can try to set `gfx.webrender.blob-images = false`. As I see that will affect only font of sidebar and library.
But I still have not investigated how it will affect other UI elements or web pages.

P.S. to disable antialiased fonts in Firefox interface on Windows 10 we also need to set `gfx.e10s.font-list.shared = false` + if you have 4K display with 200% scaling you need to set `High DPI scaling override` to "System" in `firefox.exe` properties.